# php - how to ignore content-length for post multipart data

Tags: php, post, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have an IP-camera that on trigger uploads JPG picture to my apache-php web server.

camera sends POST request with multipart data separated with boundaries, and it is ok in most cases.

but sometimes (every ~5th picture) camera sends wrong content-length (very big number, 139TB). that is some bug in camera software. $_REQUEST and $_FILES arrays are empty when this problem occurs.

except wrong content-length, everything else is fine inside request,
i listen-ed it with NETCAT and parsed picture well, it was ok (14KB only)

so if i can just tell php (php.ini or something) to ignore content-length and read post vars by boundary, everything will be fine.

is there such switch for php?

update:

after analyse, it seems that in case of this camera,

```
 wrongContentLength is always == correctLength + 139736760975360
                              == correctLength + 0x00007f1700000000
```

which is maybe caused by some 32bit - 64bit mixup.

But only way to ignore the problem is manualy parsing `php://input` which is readable when problem ocurres ...reading boundary from getallheaders(), and parsing file-data between two of them.

Comment: I had a very similar issue with a blood pressure monitor that was sending wonky post requests. Since I could only set the receiving IP address and Port on the machines, I wrote a socket listener on a custom port that listened for the messages, fixed the wonky request, and then sent the request to the proper web server. Since the request is just text, I read it all in, fixed it, sent it to the server, read out the response, and sent the response to the original machine. Took very little time.

Comment: @kainaw, i tested now, yes port can be changed for this camera too (but not subfolder)... i can try that approach, did you use C or what for simplest proxy content-length fixer program?

Comment: @kainaw, hm maybe i can just "delete content length" with your approach and simple "socat" + "grep -v" combination.